# A series about $n!$ and Riemann zeta function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Compute 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( \frac{n^n}{n!e^n}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}} \right)}.
$$
By the software Mathematica, I find
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( \frac{n^n}{n!e^n}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}} \right)}=-\frac{2}{3}-\frac{\zeta \left( 1/2 \right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.
$$

Comment: @TheSimpliFire The terms of the series converge to $0$, but there is no reason why the sum has to be close to $0$.

Comment: In terms of the Lambert function we have $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{n-1}(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}z^n=W_0(z)$ by Lagrange inversion formula and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-ns} ds}{\sqrt{\pi s}}$ holds by the inverse Laplace transform. In particular
$$ t = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{n-1} t^n}{n! e^{nt}} $$
holds for any $t$ in a neighbourhood of the origin, together with
$$ 1 = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{n}}{n!e^{nt}}(t^{n-1}-t^n).$$

Comment: Now it should not be difficult to recover the mentioned identity by playing with the Laplace transform / [Ramanujan's master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem).

Comment: @MarcoCantarini: on the other hand such coefficients are related to Bernoulli numbers and values of the $\zeta$ function, so that can be seen as a convolution between two similar generating functions, related to $\log\Gamma$. This can be useful: $$ \frac{n^n}{n!e^n}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(e^{e^{i\theta}-1-i\theta}\right)^n\,d\theta.$$

Answer (score 12):

Well, $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\zeta\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)$ is the $\zeta$-regularization of the divergent series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$, hence the problem boils down to finding the $\zeta$-regularization of the divergent series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^n}{n!e^n}$. As pointed out in the comments,

$$ W(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{n-1}(-1)^{n-1}}{n!}x^n $$
holds for any $x\in\left(-\frac{1}{e},\frac{1}{e}\right)$ by Lagrange inversion theorem, hence
$$ ze^{-z} W'(-ze^{-z})=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^n}{n!e^{nz}}z^{n}=\frac{z}{1-z} =\sum_{n\geq 1}z^n\tag{1}$$
holds for any $z\in(-W(e^{-1}),1)$. Pretty strange identity, I can give you that.
Similarly, over the same interval
$$ -W(-z e^{-z})=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!e^{nz}}z^n = z \tag{2}$$
$$ 1=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{n}}{n!e^{nz}}z^{n-1}-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{n}}{n!e^{nz}}z^{n}=\frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{z}{1-z}.\tag{3}$$
Since $\zeta(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$, it should not be difficult to prove from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that the $\zeta$-regularization of $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^n}{n!e^n}$ equals $-\frac{2}{3}$ as wanted, for instance by computing $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{n-1-k}}{n!e^n}$ for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{n-2}}{n!e^n}=\int_{-1/e}^{1}\frac{W(x)}{x}\,dx = \frac{1}{2},\qquad \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{n-3}}{n!e^n}=-\int_{-1/e}^{1}\frac{W(x)}{x}(1+\log(-x))\,dx=\frac{5}{12} $$
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{n-4}}{n!e^n}=\frac{7}{18},\qquad \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{n-4}}{n!e^n}=\frac{1631}{4320},$$
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{n-1-k}}{n!e^n}= \frac{1}{\Gamma(k)}\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)(x-1-\log x)^{k-1}\,dx.\tag{4} $$
Indeed the substitution $x=e^{-s}$ in $(4)$ and the integral representation for the $\zeta$ function complete the proof.

Comment: The RHS of (4) requires $k$ to be natural number, but we need $k=-1$ for the value of the regularization. Then can you please clarify that step?

Comment: The RHS of $(4)$ requires $k$ to be a real number $>0$. On the other hand $(4)$ leads to an integral representation for $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{n-1-k}}{n!e^n}-\frac{1}{n^{k+1}\sqrt{2\pi n}}$$ which can be analytically continued by integration by parts.

Comment: Thank you. I see that your method can generalize to the series $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{n^{n+1}}{n!e^n}-\sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi}}+\frac{1}{12\sqrt{2\pi n}}\right)$$

Comment: @i707107: you're welcome. Indeed both my method and Marco's can be extended to tackle such series; the involved computations are not that pleasant, but they are straightforward with the help of a CAS. That might be an interesting follow-up question.

Comment: Just a little bit simpler formula than your (4), can be obtained either by integration by parts, or using $W'(ze^{-z})$, is $$\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{n^n}{n!e^n n^s} = \frac1{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^1 (x-1-\log x)^{s-1} dx$$, which is valid at $\Re(s)>\frac12$.

Comment: We have $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{n^{n+1}}{n!e^n}-\sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi}}+\frac{1}{12\sqrt{2\pi n}}\right)=-\frac 4{135}-\frac{\zeta(-1/2)}{\sqrt{2\pi}} + \frac{\zeta(1/2)}{12\sqrt{2\pi}}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Taking $$F\left(x\right)=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!e^{n}}x^{n}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{x^{n}}{n^{3/2}}=-W\left(-\frac{x}{e}\right)-\frac{\mathrm{Li}_{3/2}\left(x\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}},\,\left|x\right|<1$$ where $W\left(x\right)$ is the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and $\mathrm{Li}_{3/2}\left(x\right)$ is the [Polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm), we obtain, differentiating both sides,that $$\sum_{n\geq1}\left(\frac{n^{n}}{n!e^{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\right)x^{n-1}=-\frac{W\left(-\frac{x}{e}\right)}{x\left(W\left(-\frac{x}{e}\right)+1\right)}-\frac{\mathrm{Li}_{1/2}\left(x\right)}{x\sqrt{2\pi}}$$ so $$\sum_{n\geq1}\left(\frac{n^{n}}{n!e^{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\right)=\lim_{x\rightarrow1^{-}}\left(-\frac{W\left(-\frac{x}{e}\right)}{x\left(W\left(-\frac{x}{e}\right)+1\right)}-\frac{\mathrm{Li}_{1/2}\left(x\right)}{x\sqrt{2\pi}}\right).$$ Now, [we know](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog/06/01/02/01/01/) that $$\mathrm{Li}_{v}\left(z\right)=\left(\Gamma\left(1-v\right)\left(1-z\right)^{v-1}+\zeta\left(v\right)\right)\left(1+O\left(\left|1-z\right|\right)\right),v\neq1,\,z\rightarrow1$$  and now we claim $$-\frac{W\left(-\frac{x}{e}\right)}{x\left(W\left(-\frac{x}{e}\right)+1\right)}\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\left(1-x\right)}}-\frac{2}{3}$$ as $x\rightarrow1^{-}$. This is true because, [since](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ProductLog/06/01/02/) $$W\left(z\right)\sim-1+\sqrt{2ze+2}-\frac{2}{3}e\left(z+\frac{1}{e}\right)$$ as $z\rightarrow-1/e$, we have $$-\frac{W\left(-\frac{x}{e}\right)}{x\left(W\left(-\frac{x}{e}\right)+1\right)}\sim\frac{1-\sqrt{2\left(1-x\right)}+\frac{2}{3}\left(1-x\right)}{x\sqrt{2\left(1-x\right)}-\frac{2}{3}\left(1-x\right)x}$$ $$=\frac{1}{x}\left(-1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\left(1-x\right)}}\left(\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{2-2x}/3}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{x}\left(-1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\left(1-x\right)}}\sum_{k\geq0}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2-2x}}{3}\right)^{k}\right)$$ $$=\frac{1}{x}\left(-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\left(1-x\right)}}+O\left(\sqrt{1-x}\right)\right)$$ then the claim.

Comment: (+1) This is a nice way of avoiding a double transformation via $\mathcal{L},\mathcal{L}^{-1}$. Good job, as usual. Is the next step to compute $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{n^{n+1}}{n!e^n}-\sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi}}+\frac{1}{12\sqrt{2\pi n}}\right)$$ ?

Comment: A minor fix: I believe $\sqrt{2ze+1}$ should be $\sqrt{2ze+2}$. It does not affect anything, the relevant term of the asymptotics stays $-\frac{2}{3}(ez+1)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you, fixed. I upvoted your answer this morning (as usual, I like your answers more than mine). Yes, I think the next step is the series you write. I'm not sure that my method works also in this case, probably there is something to change.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general answer to the followup question by Jack D'Aurizio.

**Proposition**

> Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We have the asymptotic expansion
>   $$
> n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n} \frac{n^n}{e^n} \left[ 1+ \frac1{12n} +\frac1{288n^2}-\frac{139}{51840n^3}-\frac{157}{2488320n^4}+\cdots \right]
> $$

Note that this is not a convergent series, but an asymptotic expansion. The error in the truncated series is asymptotically equal to the first omitted term. Regard the series on the right as an element of the ring of power series over rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}[[T]]$. 
$$
S(T)=1+ \frac1{12}T+\frac1{288}T^2-\frac{139}{51840}T^3-\frac{157}{2488320}T^4 + \cdots. 
$$
Consider the multiplicative inverse of $S(T)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[[T]]$.
$$
S^{-1}(T)=1-\frac1{12}T+ g_2 T^2 + g_3 T^3 + g_4 T^4 + \cdots. 
$$
Let $Y_s(T)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} h_n(s) T^n \in\mathbb{Q}[s][[T]]$ be defined by
$$
\left(\frac12 T^2\right)^{s-1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} h_n(s) T^n = \left[ \frac12 T^2 + \frac13 T^3 + \frac14 T^4+\cdots \right]^{s-1}.
$$
Then we have

**Theorem**

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^p\left[ \frac{n^n}{n!e^n}- \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n}} \sum_{k=0}^p \frac{g_k}{n^k}\right]=(-2)^p p!h_{2p+1}(-p)  - \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{k=0}^p g_k \zeta\left(k+\frac12-p\right).$$

With $p=0$, it is the original series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[\frac{n^n}{n!e^n} - \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\right]=-\frac23 - \frac{\zeta\left(\frac12\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
$$

With $p=1$, it gives the value of 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{n^{n+1}}{n!e^n} - \sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi}} + \frac{1}{12\sqrt{2\pi n}}\right] = -\frac 4{135} - \frac{\zeta\left(-\frac12\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}} + \frac{\zeta\left(\frac12\right)}{12\sqrt{2\pi}}.
$$

Comment: (+1) Very nice!!! My remark was wrong, thank you to find the right sense! :D